# How to solve $0 = \cos x − \cosh x + 1$?

Tags: trigonometry, dynamical-systems, hyperbolic-functions

The question is around solving a dynamical system and finding the equilibrium points, and I'm not sure where to take solving this equation for the 2 values of $x$.

Edit: To clarify, the question asks to analyse the dynamical system graphically.

Comment: From where does this equation come? I think you will need a numerical method.

Comment: There's no analytical solution to this, although there are (at least) 2 points that solve the equation.

Comment: You wont be able to find an analytic function, You'll have more luck if you try some [root finding function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm) such as [Newtons method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method)

Comment: This is equivalent to $$2\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^{4n+2}}{(4n+2)!}=1$$ hence the exactly two solutions with equal absolute values. Apart from that...

Comment: You Can also write $$e^x+e^{-x}=e^{ix}+e^{-ix}+2$$

Comment: draw graph of $coshx$ and that of $1+cosx$ you'll find ..........$1+cosx$ intersect $coshx$ at two points since that point will lie in interval $\left(0,\dfrac{\pi}{2} \right)U \left(-\dfrac{\pi}{2},0\right)$ ..so use newton raphson method to get exact roots .

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, the question asks to analyse the equation graphically.

Comment: one root will be $x=0.999$ and other will be $x= -0.999$

Comment: @veereshpandey I'm not familiar with the newton raphson method unfortunately.

Comment: $\cosh\left(x\right) = \cos\left(\mathrm{i}x\right)$

Answer (score 2):

the blue coloured graph is of $ \ cosx $ and green coloured graph is of $\cosh x$
[image]

zooming inside red rectangular region of $[-2,2] \times [0,3]$

you get  $2$ solutions $x=0.999$ and $x=-0.999$ (marked as black points) you can

solve it by numerical technique of finding roots

Comment: does it matter that in the question the equation is -coshx?

Comment: yes it does matter............ if  your equation was $0= cosx+coshx+1$ i.e, $+coshx$ in place of $-coshx$ then it will have no solution ...means then there is no real value of $ x $satisfying this equation

Comment: so shouldn't the plot in your graph be of - coshx rather than just coshx?

Comment: no...... your equation was $cosx-coshx+1=0$ which can be rewritten as $cosx+1= +coshx$ ...it means now you plot two graphs one is of $+coshx$ which is the term on $RHS$ and other of $1+cosx$ which is the term on the $LHS$ and check how many times they intersect.with each others .and then..count the number  of intersection points(which is here 2)....... and that count is nothing but the number of solutions(roots) to your equation and those are  $x=0.999$, $x=-0.999$ respectively

Comment: okay i understand now, thank you

Comment: Use `\cos` and `\cosh` for function names

Comment: okay .....got it !

Comment: To "complete" the graphical analysis and demonstrate your last point, you could add a zoom of the graphs to the rectangle $[-2,2]\times[0,3]$.

Comment: thank you .....i edited as you said .

Answer (score 1):

For $|x|\ge 2\ln 2$ you get $\cosh(x)-1\ge \frac12(4+\frac14)-1=1+\frac18$ so that there can be no solutions of $\cos x=\cosh x-1$ in this region. Inside the interval $|x|<2\ln 2$ the approximations $\cos x\approx 1-\frac12x^2$ and $\cosh x=1+\frac12x^2$ are sufficiently close to predict the roots close to $x^2=1$, $x=\pm 1$. Note that the next terms cancel in $$1=\cosh x-\cos x=x^2+\frac1{12}x^6+\frac2{10!}x^{10}+\dots$$ so that in the next approximation
$x^2\approx 1-\frac1{12}$, $x\approx \pm (1-\frac1{24})\approx\pm0.96$ which gives an idea for the range of the exact solution. Newton converges to $x=\pm 0.99862133827...$